# Add SVG element mouse event after its creation

Tags: web, svg

I have created an SVG element with an ID. I want to apply dynamically a mouse event function (e.g. `mouseout`) after its generation, by accessing it by its id (`getElementById`).

I have tried the following:

```
svgDocument.getElementById(selectedId).setAttribute(
   'onmouseout', DeselectedPointMouseOut(selectedId)
);
```

and the following:

```
svgDocument.getElementById(selectedId).onmouseout(function());
```

But these did not work.

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried so far to share?

Comment: anybody to help me? Dear stack!, please answer my question or show me some useful links.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close in your first example but there are a few different problems that prevent it from working as you expected.

Firstly, the `onmouseout` attribute expects to be assigned a string containing some JavaScript code, not an actual JavaScript function. You can assign a JavaScript function directly using the `addEventListener` method instead of the `setAttribute` method. This will also allow multiple event handlers to be applied at the same time.

The second problem is with how you referenced the function you wish to use as an event handler. When you write parentheses after a function name it means that the function will be executed right there in your call, but what you actually want to do is *pass* the function as a parameter so that it can be called *later*. It will be the code that eventually calls your function (which in your case will be the SVG renderer itself, when the user moves the mouse out of the element) that will use the parentheses to pass a set of arguments into the function you provided.

Finally, an event handler function has a very specific *signature*; that is, the set of arguments it expects. It will be passed an `Event` object that describes some details about the event that occured.

Putting this all together we can adjust the code as follows:

```
// First define the event handler function.
function deselectedPointMouseOut(event) {
    // do your event handling in here
}

// Now attach the event handler to the element.
svgDocument.getElementById(selectedId).addEventListener(
    "mouseout", deselectedPointMouseOut, true
);
```

You can learn more about the `Event` object passed into your event handler, and event handling in general, in [the MDN article on `Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Event). In particular, the `mouseout` event results in a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent) object being passed in to the event handler.

That extra `true` parameter to `addEventListener` is a detail of how event handling works which you can read about in [the documentation for this method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) if you are interested.

Comment: (In my answer I assumed you were using JavaScript, because you didn't specify in your question.)

Comment: thanks a lot, but your answer did not work.Maybe it is because of my script type (<script type="text/ecmascript">) and working on svg elements.

Comment: Can you tell me a little bit more? What environment is this script running in? Were there any error messages when you tried the code I suggested? Anything else that might help me guess what went wrong? I wrote this assuming a normal web browser runtime environment with a standard DOM interface, but perhaps your environment is different somehow.

Comment: If my answer helped them please consider marking it as your accepted answer. Also, if you had to do make some additional changes to my answer to make it work please let me know and I'll update the answer to include them, as an aid to people who find this question in the future.